# Orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing $v_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1,1,\ldots,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples, orthonormal

I would like to construct the orthonormal basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $v_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1,1,\ldots,1)$. I am looking for an analytic formulation of all vectors of the basis.

Any hints or idea are very welcome :). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to a dire need to procrastinate I decided to work out explicitly the two suggestions that have been made so far.

Experimentally, it seems that applying the Gram-Schmidt process to the vectors $v_1, e_1, e_2, \ldots, e_{n-1}$ gives a very neat result:
$$\begin{matrix}
v_1 = \Big( & \frac1{\sqrt n}, & \frac1{\sqrt n}, & \frac1{\sqrt n}, & \ldots, & \frac1{\sqrt n} & \Big), \\
v_2 = \Big( & \sqrt{\frac{n-1}n}, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}, & \ldots, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}} & \Big), \\
v_3 = \Big( & 0, & \sqrt{\frac{n-2}{n-1}}, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{(n-1)(n-2)}}, & \ldots, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{(n-1)(n-2)}} & \Big), \\
v_4 = \Big( & 0, & 0, & \sqrt{\frac{n-3}{n-2}}, & \ldots, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{(n-2)(n-3)}} & \Big), \\
\vdots
\end{matrix}$$
all the way down to
$$\begin{matrix}v_n = \Big(0, & \ldots, & 0, & \sqrt{\frac12}, & \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\cdot1}}\Big).\end{matrix}$$
So apparently the last $n-2$ vectors are the same as those for $\mathbb R^{n-1}$, just lifted to $\mathbb R^n$ by prepending a $0$. Presumably someone can prove it via induction.

On the other hand, inspired by MPW's answer we can take the unique reflection $T$ such that $Te_1=v_1$, and then let $v_i = Te_i$. That means $T = I - 2uu^T$, where $u=(e_1-v_1)/\|e_1-v_1\|$, which after some algebra gives
$$\begin{align}
T &= I-2\frac{(e_1-v_1)(e_1-v_1)^T}{(e_1-v_1)^T(e_1-v_1)} \\
&= I - \frac1{n-\sqrt n}\Big(nE_{11} - \sqrt nE_{1*} - \sqrt nE_{*1} + E_{**}\Big),
\end{align}$$
where I'm using $E_{ab}$ to denote the matrix with ones in row(s) $a$ and column(s) $b$ and zeroes everywhere else.
This turns out to be
$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac1{\sqrt n} & \frac1{\sqrt n} & \frac1{\sqrt n} & \ldots & \frac1{\sqrt n} \\
\frac1{\sqrt n} & 1-\frac1{n-\sqrt n} & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} & \ldots & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} \\
\frac1{\sqrt n} & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} & 1-\frac1{n-\sqrt n} & \ldots & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\frac1{\sqrt n} & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} & \frac{-1}{n-\sqrt n} & \ldots & 1-\frac1{n-\sqrt n},
\end{pmatrix}$$
and the vectors $v_i$ are just the $n$ columns of $T$.

Both solutions are quite nice. The solution from reflection is more symmetrical, while the one from Gram-Schmidt has a more inductive structure.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for sharing your ideas :). I like the reflection approach very much. It is very elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Start with the canonical orthonormal basis $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$. Let $T$ be the rotation that sends $e_1$ to your $v_1$. Then $\{Te_1,\ldots,Te_n\}$is what you want.

Comment: Is this any more than a reformulation of the problem?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Certainly. Is it hard to determine the exact formula for the rotation? No, I'm just lazy--but I can compute it and post it if desired. I thought that might be easy. The point is you absolutely do not need to use G-S for this

Comment: Maybe I just misunderstood what you mean by rotation. Do you want one that the subspace orthogonal to $e_1$ and $v_1$ is fixed by $T$? This makes sense.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: I confess I was thinking it would be unique, but I see upon further reflection that it isn't.

Comment: "Reflection" -- haha! I was just about to point out that the *reflection* that sends $e_1$ to $v$ *is* unique, and easy to express analytically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Answer (score 0):

Are the $n$ vectors given or not? If you already have a set of $n$ vectors containing $v_1$, you can employ Gram-Schmidt process. Otherwise, you need to obtain $n$ linearly independent vectors first.